# iOS UITabBar : Remove top shadow gradient line iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Can anyone please give me solution for the `UITabbar` top shadow gradient line.i have tried with setting `tabBar.shadowImage = nil` `shadowImage` Customisation works for iOS 9 or prior. but not working for iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

For `iOS 10` you can use below lines of in Application delegate class method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImgName"]];
    [UITabBar appearance].layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    [UITabBar appearance].clipsToBounds = YES;

    return YES;
}
```

May be you can try below code, but is not recommended to use private API:

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
```

Solution suggested by **Shubham bairagi** to Remove top shadow gradient line `iOS 10`:

```
tabBar.subviews[0].subviews[1].isHidden = true
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, I have tried this way also but have custom tabbar with 64px height. By using above code tabbar will clipsToBounds to 49px height.

Comment: Check the edited code if your app is not for appstore or for private use@Shubhambairagi

Comment: Thanks alot @Ronak, I have tried with tabBar.subviews[0].subviews[1].isHidden = true . it works thanks for your efforts.